# Azure Pipeline - YAML how to unzip a downloaded secure file and then execute an exe

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Pipeline using a YAML that has one task that downloads a zipped secure file:

```
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: Download Testpipelineapp
  name: testPipelineapp
  inputs:
    secureFile: TestPipelineapp.zip
```

The download happens perfectly, but then I need to extract the contents because inside is an .EXE that I need to execute.

Any clue on how can I do this? I'm new to YAML and Azure Devops.

Answer (score 2):

I found how:

```
- task: ExtractFiles@1
  inputs:
    archiveFilePatterns: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/TestPipelineapp.zip'
    cleanDestinationFolder: false
    overwriteExistingFiles: true
```

Then in order to execute the .EXE file I had to add a CMD script task

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: TestPipelineapp.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options, depending on what's installed in your agent.

The hosted agent comes with a recent enough version of PowerShell to be able to use the [`Expand-Archive` PowerShell function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-7.2). And it has `7z` installed, so you could call that too.

```
- script: |
      7z x path-to-downloaded-file.zip  path-to-extract-to
      path-to-extract-to\myexecutable.exe
```

```
# PowerShell
# Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    #filePath: # Required when targetType == FilePath
    #arguments: # Optional
    script: |
         Expand-archive -file path-to-downloaded-file.zip -Destinationpath path-to-extract-to
         & path-to-extract-to\myexecutable.exe
    #errorActionPreference: 'stop' # Optional. Options: default, stop, continue, silentlyContinue
    #warningPreference: 'default' # Optional. Options: default, stop, continue, silentlyContinue
    #informationPreference: 'default' # Optional. Options: default, stop, continue, silentlyContinue
    #verbosePreference: 'default' # Optional. Options: default, stop, continue, silentlyContinue
    #debugPreference: 'default' # Optional. Options: default, stop, continue, silentlyContinue
    #failOnStderr: false # Optional
    #ignoreLASTEXITCODE: false # Optional
    pwsh: true
    #workingDirectory: # Optional
```

Then there's the built-in task:

```
# Extract files
# Extract a variety of archive and compression files such as .7z, .rar, .tar.gz, and .zip
- task: ExtractFiles@1
  inputs:
    #archiveFilePatterns: '**/*.zip' 
    destinationFolder: 
    #cleanDestinationFolder: true 
    #overwriteExistingFiles: false
    #pathToSevenZipTool:
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/extract-files?view=azure-devops